# how to change name of uploaded file in php in the script below

Tags: php, file-upload, upload

I copied the php upload script from w3schools and I did some changes to change the file name.

the only thing that I could do was to add a random name to the first of the file name but I need to remove its original name from the uploaded file.

for example I have a file named "abc.jpg"

After I upload this file, I can change it to a random name + original name like this "2716c3f3e9d6dd0a2b89f047b938750520aaa.jpg"

How can I delete the original name "aaa" from the end of uploaded file name in this code?

```
$rand = md5(md5(time()).md5(microtime())).rand(10,25);
$target_dir = "images/futsal/";
$file = $rand . basename($_FILES['fileperson']["name"]);
$target_file = $target_dir . $rand . basename($_FILES['fileperson']["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES['fileperson']["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES['fileperson']["size"] > 50000000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['fileperson']["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "file ". $file . " uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
$target_file = $target_dir . $rand . basename($_FILES['fileperson']["name"]);
```

With the following:

```
$extension = preg_replace('/.+?(\.[^.]+)$/', '$1', $_FILES['fileperson']['name']);
$extension = $extension ? $extension : '.unknown';
$target_file = $target_dir . $rand . $extension;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the uploaded file name at the end of the `$target_file` variable.

Update the code to remove the `$_FILES['fileperson']["name"]` in the `$target_file`.

```
$rand = md5(md5(time()).md5(microtime())).rand(10,25);
$target_dir = "images/futsal/";
$imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES['fileperson']["name"],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$file = $rand . $imageFileType;
$target_file = $target_dir . $file;
```